# Ubuntu boot mode conflict when installing to new (empty) SSD

Tags: 16.04, uefi

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 from a USB onto my brand new SSD, but I get the following message (see below). I've seen a bunch of posts about this, but none involving installing onto a new hard drive that doesn't currently have any operating systems installed. At an earlier stage in the process the computer told me that no OS's were detected.

I get no response whether I click "Continue", "Go Back", or even try to close the window. Help?

The message:

"This machine's firmware has started the installer in UEFI mode but it
looks like there may be existing operating systems already installed using
"BIOS compatibility mode". If you continue to install Debian in UEFI mode,
it might be difficult to reboot the machine into any BIOS-mode operating
systems later.

If you wish to install in UEFI mode and don't care about keeping the
ability to boot one of the existing systems, you have the option to force
that here. If you wish to keep the option to boot an existing operating
system, you should choose NOT to force UEFI installation here."

Comment: do you have Windows installed in Legacy mode?

Comment: it's a brand new drive. nothing is installed on it.

Comment: ok two things to check. 1) is the ATA controler set to AHCI and 2) is the drive partitioned with GPT?

Comment: sorry, how do I check these things?

Comment: could this have something to do with it?: when I run ubuntu live directly from the USB LiveDisk, and then run `sudo fdisk -l`, the USB LiveDisk itself is listed as Type: EFI (FAT-12/16/32). it's also listed as "Disklabel type: dos"

Comment: Open the firmware settings, usually pressing F2, F10, or F12 while booting; though it could be any function key or esc. look for a HDD controller setting. If it is not present then it is probably AHCI. The Partitioning can be checked with any partitioning tool. The installer should let you open a command shell. `parted`  should be included

Comment: ran `dmesg | grep -i ahci`, and it did find some lines, so I assume it is ahci. running `sudo parted -l`, it says "Partition table: unknown"

Comment: Partition the disk GPT. `sudo parted /dev/sda mklabel gpt`. this should set a GPT partition table that is empty.

Comment: Is this the only drive, or do you have Windows in BIOS/MBR boot mode on another drive? That may be what installer is seeing. And best to have all installs in same boot mode, but also better to use UEFI if hardware is UEFI.

Comment: Yes this is the only drive.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the SSD is new, I decided to go with the default option of "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" instead of specifying my own partition table as I usually do. And this led to a successful install.

My guess as to the problem is that I was specifying the root partition as "ext4 filesystem" instead of ESP. Can someone comment as to whether this diagnosis is correct?

EDIT: It is correct. I confirmed by re-installing with my own partition table as follows: EFI System Partition (ESP) at the beginning of the drive with around 570MB of space, and then partitions for root, home, and swap. Thanks for the help!

Comment: you are not correct, the issue is that the disk is partitioned MBR instead of GPT. So without the ESP, the installer thought that the drive  had a Legacy System installed on it. As I stated in the above comments, EFI prefers a GPT partitioning. It can run on an MBR disk, so leave it if already installed. But if you reinstall, consider switching to GPT partitioning.

Comment: @ravery how can I partition GPT? Can I do that using Ubuntu bootable usb or do I need gparted bootable usb for that?